# My graphql server query is returning null value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql

I wrote a graphql API that connects to a Mongo database allocated in my machine using the MongoDB driver, and have a `Query` resolver

```
getServiceByType: async (_, args) => {
      const serviceData = await db
        .collection("service")
        .find({ type: args.type })
        .toArray();
      let services = [];
      return await serviceData.map(async (value) => {
        const dbUser = await db
          .collection("user")
          .findOne(ObjectID(value.user));
        const userFiltered = pick(dbUser, ["username", "email"]);
        const { user, ...withoutUser } = value;
        const filledValue = { ...withoutUser, user: userFiltered };
        services.push(filledValue);
        console.log(services);
        return services;
      });
    },
```

That should return the value for the `Service` schema and the `User` related with it.
The `console.log(services)` shows the result that i expect

```
[
  {
    _id: 5f1ca8e2d866d3536c102e07,
    name: 'Second Service',
    description: 'Creating second service for test',
    type: 'Food',
    user: { username: 'TestUser', email: 'Test@test.com' }
  }
]
```

But in the `Graphql Playground` throws the following error message:

`"message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Service._id."`

I don't know what's wrong with the `Query` resolver.

**edit**

Result type def looks like this:

```
  type User {
    _id: ID!
    name: String!
    username: String!
    password: String!
    email: String!
    type: String!
    country: String!
    transactions: Int
  }

  type Service {
    _id: ID!
    name: String!
    description: String!
    user: User!
    type: String!
  }
```

Comment: result type defs? ... this _id not recognized as valid (for return type) int/string, dropped before returning result - just cast to desired shape/type before pushing into array

Comment: `_id: 5f1ca8e2d866d3536c102e07,` is not valid as int or string (ID allowed types), not valid as value in json, too